# How can I export & import firefox addons settings

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

Is is possible to export (and import) firefox addons settings?  I mean addons data. not their installable `.xpi`.

For example, I've collected a custom blacklist for AdBlock on my Windows, and I want to have it on my Ubuntu

Comment: On further thought, **this isn't a dupe**. He just want to export the **settings** of the addon. (As he clearly would have seen if I had more than just *one* sip of coffe.)

Answer (score 9):

All preferences are stored inside `prefs.js` file inside your profile folder, using a javascript syntax:

```
[...]
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.capacity", 358400);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.smart_size.first_run", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.smart_size.use_old_max", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.smart_size_cached_value", 358400);
[...]    
user_pref("extensions.grabanddrag-version", "3.2.0");
user_pref("extensions.grabanddrag.button", 1);
user_pref("extensions.grabanddrag.flickon", false);
user_pref("extensions.grabanddrag.grabCursor", "auto");
[...]
```

Once you shut down Firefox, you may grep all your addon configs and append the lines to your new profile file:

```
grep extensions. oldprofile\prefs.js >> newprofile\prefs.js
```

or with just a single addon (assuming you've found it's name):

```
grep extensions.grabanddrag. oldprofile\prefs.js >> newprofile\prefs.js
```

---

To avoid having duplicate entries (it's javascript, so the **last entry** counts), before you import your settings, you may also purge same config settings from your new profile:

```
grep -v extensions.grabanddrag. newprofile\prefs.js > newprofile\prefs.js
```

The `-v` attribute reverses the way grep works.

---

This will of course move config only. You need to install the addon separately.

Comment: You're such a life saver; you and beyond compare :)

Comment: command file > file  will truncate file before writing, so command (grep) will have no content from file to operate on.  MIchal, a better way would be: 
{ grep -v extensions.grabanddrag. oldprofile\prefs.js; 
  grep     extensions.grabanddrag. oldprofile\prefs.js; } >> newprofile\prefs.js

Answer (score 3):

Can you try setting up [Firefox Sync](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-take-your-bookmarks-and-tabs-with-you)?

> Firefox Sync is a service that lets you synchronize your bookmarks,
>   history, passwords, add-ons and open tabs with another copy of Firefox
>   – like one on another computer or on a mobile phone. This article
>   briefly explains how it all works and why you'd want to use it.

Firefox Sync syncs your Firefox data (passwords, settings, add-ons) between multiple installations of Firefox. I have not used it to sync add-ons, but the other data is synced seamlessly.

Comment: I use this. Very handy.

Comment: Does it sync the addons *settings* as the OP request?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/Sync/Addon_Sync#Are_Add-on_Settings_Synchronized.3F Basically the post says that it depends on the addon.

Answer (score 2):

There are two excellent extensions that would allow you to do that:

1.[Febe](http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/febe.html)

Here is a quote from its FAQ

> - Can FEBE backup/restore my extensions settings?
> - In a word ... yes.  But there is a big caveat (user beware) that comes with it.  FEBE will backup your preferences (a file called "prefs.js" that contains your extension settings) but it backs up the whole thing without making any distinctions about your installed extensions.  In other words, it backs up the ENTIRE preferences file, not just the parts needed for any individual extension.

You can read further here: [Can FEBE back up and restore extension settings?](http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/febeFAQ.html#A11)

FEBE though is more like a complete backup solution for Firefox.

There is another extension made just for backing up extension preferences:

2.[OPIE](http://softwarebychuck.com/opie/opie.html)

Here is a quote from its web page:

> - OPIE is a Firefox extension that allows you to import and export your installed extension preferences.  This is useful when installing extensions in a new profile, or synchronizing multiple Firefox installations.

I personnaly use FEBE since i need scheduled backups and other functionality available in FEBE.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) when I need to export all my Mozilla products settings/data/profiles from an host to another.

This is a more wide solution, but it will, among other things, export your extensions settings.